# Developing an Android device

Tags: android, development

I would like to create a product that has an embedded Android device for the main reason the price. Because it will be embedded into another system it doesn't need all the peripherals; no camera, gps or tilt sensor. Even the 3G is not important, but WiFi and the touchscreen (max 3.5") are.

How would you start developing such product? Buy old cheap Android phones or media players and take them apart or get in touch with a manufacturer and develop custom modules? The cost per unit is important, casing is not important because they are plastic molded.

We are talking about a prototype first but later batches of 50, so some manual labor is alright.

Comment: Given the small size of your production run, I think you'd be best off finding a device that meets your need and re-casing it.

Comment: Yes, but beware of designing around a short life product that may cease to be available just as your effort develops momentum.  That's a big risk for LCD panels too, in addition to consumer products like phones and tablets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Practically speaking, unless you are doing runs in the 1k+, or are willing to spend a lot, a manufacturer won't even bother speaking with you. You might find someone to give you a discount on 50 premade android devices, but it would probably not be a very big discount, maybe covering shipping.

As for your needs, you say you need a 3.5" touchscreen. This will limit you to android cell phones. You could find android devices without screens for much cheaper, then add a usb touchscreen separately.

**But the biggest question you should have is how will you interface the device with your product?** What do you intend to do?

Comment: The interface is an just an USB barcode reader. The rest will be done with WiFi. I have a model for a barcode reader with induction charging etc. but I want to implement a smart logic device with screen, I thought that an Android phone would be the easiest.

Comment: Only some android phones can host USB devices, and you'll probably have to hack the power system if you intend to leave a usb device permanently connected.

Answer (score 2):

While there isn't a simple solution to the stated requirement, here is one approach:

- Purchase, in retail, a *new* cheap Android phone that meets the specifications. Often the "*old cheap*" phones will be more expensive than new models, and will also suffer from spares (batteries!) sourcing.
- Also purchase an Android [Accessory Development Kit](http://developer.android.com/tools/adk/index.html) (ADK), either the official [Arduino ADK](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardADK), or one of the many clones and [ADK compatible development boards](http://www.ebay.com/itm/DFRduino-MEGA-ADK-Arduino-Compatible-/150727713024?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item2318126100) (*$49 on eBay*) out there.
  [image: Arduino ADK]
- Integrate the barcode reader into the ADK board - **The ADK is a USB *host***, so USB devices can be connected to it.

Once you have a working prototype through the steps above, either integrate all the constituent parts into a single board that integrates with a generic Android phone, or find a suitable electronics design business that will do this for you.

Comment: I have been looking ofcourse going this route, only need a touchscreen display and WiFi, both are quite expensive on an arduino based system, so I thought to be better of connecting an Android device.

Comment: This is a proposal for hardware interface to an Android device which is *not* capable of functioning as a USB host to host external devices.  However, the ADK/IOIO are not remotely cost effective in that role compared to the more recent generation of USB-host microcontrollers and their eval boards.

Comment: @ChrisStratton For a first prototype? So building a board from scratch to validate the concept is a preferred option?

Comment: @Rogier21 That is precisely what this answer addresses: You can get a basic Android phone with touch screen and wifi for under $150 in retail, add the $50 Arduino ADK clone, and you can build your first prototype.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh - no, there are far cheaper eval boards available with USB host functionality now.

Comment: @ChrisStratton The requirement includes wifi, touchscreen and usb host functionality - hence the combination of Android and "another system", stated in the question and addressed in my answer: I don't know of dev boards with all those features in a less expensive option, perhaps I need to research this further....

Comment: I could try to find an alternative route but tooling and prototyping of such boards would be too expensive for such low quantity. I could create a USB host/slave adapter which shouldn't be too difficult to make.

Comment: That's not what I proposed.  There are now cheaper, more modern options for the ADK/IOIO USB host role in a hybrid system than the ADK/IOIO.   Those boards are designs dating from when this had just become plausible but not really cost effective to use.  Fortunately technology has moved on.  So now there are choices from several vendors where not only are the chips cheaper in the long run and thus plausible to consider for an actual product, but the eval boards carrying them are drastically cheaper, priced in the $15-20 range.

Comment: I actually had a brainfart, the Raspberry Pi (A model) is not much bigger than a motherboard from a phone/mp4 player. Only no Wifi SOC.

Comment: Or display.  But notice how the pi makes the ADK look overpriced, even if it's dependence on an oddly mounted SD card makes it questionable as a direct alternative.

Comment: @ChrisStratton That's true, the idea is good, but I need extra peripherals and desoldering of all the big connectors. Finding a suitable screen is going to be a pain on itself.